# will testng initiate as many webdriver instance as test cases?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am facing a problem of Selenium Grid and TestNG. My test scripts will NOT quite the browser until all the test class are executed.

I've configed 5 Chrome instance running on my Selenium Grid, then below is my xml file

```
   <suite name="BrowserTest">            
   <test name="Test1" >
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name= "Pagetest" />
        </classes>      
    </test>   

    <test name="Test2" >
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class name= "Pagetest" />
        </classes>      
    </test>   

  <test name="Overview Page Test on ie, English" >
        <parameter name="browserName" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name= "Pagetest" />
        </classes>      
    </test> 
   </suite>
```

Here is my test scripts
    public class Pagetest {
        private WebDriver browser;

```
    public PateTest( String browser){
        // create a browser instance.
    }

   @AfterClass (or @afterTest)   
   public void afterTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("this test is done");
        this.browser.quit();
    }

   @Test
   public void test1(){
       this.browser.get("www.google.com");
       // doing some login stuff
   }

}
```

Now when I am running my test, testNG will create 3 chrome webdirver instance one by one (with running the test). but after the 1st test is done, the browser instance of 1st test is not quited until all 3 tests are done, then all the 3 chrome instance are quited almost at the same time. What I want is after the 1st test is done, it's browser instance is quited, then the 2nd test case is started, did I do something wrong or how should I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using threadlocal it would help when you are  even running tests in parallel

```
public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver=null;

@beformethod()

public void setUp
{
driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
driver.set(new ChromeDriver());
 return driver.get();
}

@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser() {

{
 driver.get().quit();
}
```

Comment: Will this apply to selenium grid? It now seems that my script will initializes as many instances as it needs and then running them. But my problem is I only set instance = 5 in my selenium grid, so if there's more than 5 classes in my xml file, as script cannot initiate enough instances for testing, it will be hanging there until time out. I am wondering how could I rung the classes in the xml one by one

Comment: are you running the tests in parallel when you run it in parallel it will create all the instances it need as for grid just replace protected ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = null;, can uou post your @beforetest code

Comment: I think I figured out why my problem happens. I was NOT using any "beforeTest" annotations, thus testNG initiates all the test classes at the beginning, then executing them 1 by 1. If I add an "beforeclass" annotation before my test class constructor (also change the constructor name to something like "setupClass()" ), then my problem is solved.